# How can I restrict view access to a page type in SilverStripe to admin users only?

Tags: silverstripe, access-control

How can I restrict view access to a page type in SilverStripe to admin users only?

I'd prefer to do it through the code itself, but through the CMS would be good to know too.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22239021/612253) gets me most of the way there; I just need to find the Administrators group perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the answer you linked to is what you need to do. To get the ID of a group you could do something like this `Group::get()->filter('Code', 'administrators')->first()->ID;`.

Another alternative would be to check for permissions, e.g.

```
public function canView($member = null) {
    return Permission::checkMember($member, "ADMIN") !== false;
}
```

As Willr [mentions here](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/19005#post311182) checking for permissions would possibly be better.

You might find these APIs useful:

- [Permission](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Permission.html)
- [Group](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Group.html)
- [Member](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Member.html)